# Laravel Controller Middleware for Resources

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am trying to use a middleware on a resource route.

My Route ->
`Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`

My Middleware ->

```
$user = Auth::user();

    if(Auth::check()) {
        if($user->is_admin) {
           return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } 
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```

My Controller Constructor ->

`$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('admin')->only('posts.destroy');`

My Goal is to let only administrators destroy the post and not others.

But when I use 
`php artisan route:list`, the middleware shown are web,auth.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you register the middleware in the Kernel? In any case see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: @Andrew Ya it is added  as `'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,`

Comment: For argument's sake, try to add the middleware globally and see if it hits it. As in wrap all your routes with a route group and place a `die()` or something in the middelware itself and access any route.

Comment: @Andrew If I add only `$this->middleware('admin');` It shows under `php artisan route:list` But I want it to apply only to certain routes. Any Solution?

Comment: We can work something out ofc, just wanted to make sure it works.

Comment: Oh okay! Btw I'm new to Laravel so the steps I took are correct or wrong?

Comment: The steps you took are very much correct. I'm a bit caught up with stuff but i'll return with an asnwer shortly.

Comment: @Andrew thanks! Answer by Amit worked! `('destroy')` works instead of `('posts.destroy')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it as:

```
$this->middleware('admin')->only('destroy');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: Thanks! That works! My route was named `posts.destroy` and so I thought that would work.